# Add variables to list and sort by size

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following set of code, but am unsure as to how to sort the variables. All of the threads I viewed discuss sorting lists, but I want to sort the variables then have them print out in descending order.

```
print 'Welcome to the Cafe!'
print 'This is our list of items on our small menu'
print ' -------------- Sandwiches -----------------'
print '1 : Grilled Cheese $2.00'
print '2 : Tuna Sandwich $2.00'
print '3 : Chicken Sandwich $2.00'
print ' -------------- Drinks ---------------------'
print '4 : Water $1.00'
print '5 : Soda $1.50'
 '6 : Coffee $2.00'
print ' -------------- Salads ---------------------'
print '7 : Chicken Caesar Salad $4.00'
print '8 : Tuna Salad $3.50'
print '9 : House Salad $2.00'
print 'Enter 10 when you are ready to complete your order'
endval = 0
gri = 0
tunas = 0
chics = 0
wat = 0
soda = 0
cof = 0
chic = 0
tuna = 0
hs = 0
inp = 0
total = 0
sandsub = 0
drinksub = 0
salsub = 0
while inp != 10:
    inp=raw_input('What would you like to order? ')
    if inp=='1':
            gri += 1
    elif inp=='2':
            tunas += 1
    elif inp=='3':
            chics += 1
    elif inp=='4':
            wat += 1
    elif inp=='5':
            soda += 1
    elif inp=='6':
            cof +=1
    elif inp=='7':
            chic+=1
    elif inp=='8':
            tuna +=1
    elif inp=='9':
            hs +=1
    elif inp =='10':
            break
    else:
            print('Invalid Menu Selection')
sandsub = (gri*2) + (tunas*2) + (chics*2)
drinksub = (wat*1) + (soda*1.5) + (cof*2)
salsub = (chic*4) + (tuna*3.5) + (hs*2)
total = (sandsub) + (drinksub) + (salsub)
print '---------- Sandwiches -----------'
print 'You ordered ' ,gri, ' Grilled Cheese'
print 'You ordered ' ,tunas, ' Tuna Salad Sandwiches'
print 'You ordered ' ,chics, ' Chicken Salad Sandwiches'
print 'Your sandwich subtotal comes out to : $%0.2f ' %sandsub
print '---------- Drinks --------------'
print 'You ordered ' ,wat, ' Waters'
print 'You ordered ' ,soda, ' Sodas'
print 'You ordered ' ,cof, ' Coffees'
print 'Your drinks subtotal comes out to : $%0.2f ' %drinksub
print '---------- Salads --------------'
print 'You ordered ' ,chic, ' Chick Salads'
print 'You ordered ' ,tuna, ' Tuna Salads'
print 'You ordered ' ,hs, ' House Salads'
print 'Your salad subtotal comes out to : $%0.2f ' %salsub
print '---------- Grand Total --------------'
print 'Your total comes out to : $%0.2f ' %total
print 'Enjoy your meal and have a nice day!'
```

Answer (score 0):

put all your variables in a list of 2-tuples, then sort the list

```
my_sorted_list = sorted([(gri, 'gri'), (tunas, 'tunas'), ...], reverse=True)
for value, name in my_sorted_list:
    print name, '=', value
```

ps : don't use global variable like this, a dict would be nice for this, it will avoid using the if .. elif .. if ...elif .. code

Comment: OP wants the list to be sorted in descending order.

Comment: so just use `reverse=True` as an argument to sort